# Can we really beat the speed of light?

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

This is a rather physics question but I wanted to get an insight from a chemistry perspective. I heard from some that you can beat the speed or go faster than it but is that really true. Physicists as we all know look at the theoretical possibilities but what is your insight from a chemistry-ish view.

[Here](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20121003-can-we-travel-faster-than-light) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPsG8td7C5k&t=34) for more information.

---

If we can then how much more faster is it? I heard one view into this that goes along the lines of:

If you distorted space and moved it then you would be light-years away from where you started. This seemed very *dumb* at first but as I thought about it is this anyway possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "chemistry-ish view"? I don't think chemistry has much to do with this sort of thing other than that chemistry has strong ties to physics.

Comment: Exactly thats what I mean that chemistry that has strong ties with physics. Is there anyway to explain this whole beating light in a chemistry way?

Comment: Chemistry by its very definition is mostly concerned with matter on the level of protons and electrons. There are relativistic effects involved that are also of interest to chemists but finding a way to travel faster than the speed of light wouldn't change chemistry in my opinion. I can't imagine new reactions becoming possible or anything since you would have to "cheat" anyway (like maybe distorting space) if at all possible to travel faster than the speed of light.

Comment: In the words of Dr. Kit Bowen, "Chemistry is simply condensed phase physics."

Comment: @LordStryker Or as a friend of mine put it: "Chemistry is the nice part of physics." :)

Comment: Well on Physics SE there's tag faster-than-light with 252 questions: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faster-than-light How this question could be not off-topic here?

Comment: Chemistry examines the individual "blocks" of matter and their properties, similarities and differences. Physics mainly deals with what behavior all of matter shares, and passing the speed of light is one. So, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to physics.SE.

Comment: I think the question is on-topic.  The OP clearly wants a chemist point of view.  If this happens to coincide with physics then so be it.

Comment: You aren't going to find a magical way to beat the speed of light in chemistry. Compared to contemporary physics, chemistry is a small subset which operates on a very mild energy scale, with modest distances and time intervals involved. If there were some process so crazy as to break relativity at this level, then **major** discrepancies from theory and experiment would abound in astrophysics and particle physics, and we would have detected such by now.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things that exceed the speed of light:

1. Particles in a medium such as water can enter faster than light [in that medium] but are slowed and release energy as [Cherenkov radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation).
2. The [phase velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) of a wave can exceed that of light [in that medium].
3. An arbitrary point, such as the point on a pair of scissors where blades,
   meet, can move faster than light.
4. Most puzzling to me: [entangled particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement). Einstein called this "spooky action at a distance". Although each *particle* moves at C or less, information *might be* shared between them in an indefinitely short time; see [superluminal communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_communication). Entanglement *does* apply to chemistry, as do other odd quantum effects; e.g. the detection of single photons with silver halide photography as they form an interference pattern in the [double-slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment).

Comment: Regarding entanglement, your own link says that it cannot be used to transmit information faster than $c$: *"It is not possible, however, to use this effect to transmit classical information at faster-than-light speeds[10]"*

Answer (score 2):

From classical special relativity it can be shown that anything (particle, object, electromagnetic wave, Z-wave, a dishwasher, anything) that travels faster than the speed of light (in vacuum) would violate the causality principle. In relation to chemistry, this means more qualitatively that the second law of thermodynamics would be violated. Hence I would argue that from a chemistry viewpoint traveling faster than the speed of light is impossible.